# Prove that if $f$ is holomorphic inside and on a circle of radius $R$ centered at $z_0$, then $|f(z_0)| \geq \min_{z \in C_{R}(z_0)} |f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on the closed disc of radius $R$ around some point $z_0$ and $f(z) \neq 0$, i.e. $f$ is holomorphic on the disc $D_{R}(z_0)$, show that the minimum value of $f(z)$ on the disc occurs when $z$ is on the boundary of the disc.

I start with the Cauchy integration formula $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_{R}(z_0)} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz$$

I then use the estimation lemma to show that $$|f(z_0)| =\frac{1}{2\pi i} |\int_{C_{R}(z_0)} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi i} \max_{z \in C_{R}(z_0)} |\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}|\cdot\ell(C_{R}(z_0))$$

Now we have $|z-z_0| = R$ for all $z \in C_{R}(z_0)$ and $\ell(D_{R}(z_0)) = 2\pi R$ meaning the above equation simplifies down to $$f(z_0)| \leq -i \cdot \max_{z \in C_{R}(z_0)} |f(z)|$$

This is where I get stuck, I am sure that I am closer to the solution but am not sure how to proceed.

EDIT: $f(z) \neq 0$ anywhere

Comment: this is not true; take $f(z)=z$; you need an extra condition, namely that $f$ doesn;t vanish on the disc so you can apply maximum modulus to $1/f$

Comment: Yes, I've edited my original question to reflect this. I am wondering if the proof is possible without use of the maximum modulus theorem?

Comment: what tools do you want to use? You can apply Cauchy to $1/f$ and show its maximum is on the boundary

Comment: Ah I see. So my method above is not really the correct train of thought?

Comment: You need to use the nonvanishing of $f$ essentially and that usually means using $1/f$ holomorphic

Comment: I think you meant $>$ not $\geq$ ? Because with $\geq$ it is trivially true.